# How to move the "1" down to pair with the line "Applying 7S, TQM technique in..."

Tags: tables, tabularx

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Description:} \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & \textbf{TQM} \\  Applying 7S, TQM technique in assessing the healthcare waste in various institutions was found useful in discovering important factors and helped greatly in identifying the training needs.
    \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind providing a complete code, starting with `\documentclass`, and ending with `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Description:} \tabularnewline
\midrule
 & \textbf{TQM} \tabularnewline
1 &  Applying 7S, TQM technique in assessing the healthcare waste in various institutions was found useful in discovering important factors and helped greatly in identifying the training needs.
    \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @CarlosZepeda Glad to hear. In this forum, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark, comments have a different purpose.